# how to make responsive screen resolution?

Tags: javascript, html, css

can some one help , i want to make website like youtube for streaming video , 
but i have a problem , i want make 5 div in 1 rom in 1920x1080 , and auto reduced to 4 , 3,2,1 if the screen get smaller

this the picture example

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdPAl.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ke5R.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pPkX.jpg)

hope you guys understand :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bootstrap](https://www.bootstrap.com)

Use Bootstrap! You can specify how many videos are in a row with `col-` class. 
For instance,

`<div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-6"></div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-6"></div>` 
`<div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-6"></div>` 
`<div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-6"></div>`

will give you 4 videos per row in mobile and 2 videos per row with 2 rows in desktop (There are 12 columns per row).

An alternative approach is to use CSS Grids.